# unwind segue pass data to different viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have an app which have 4 different forms. these forms can be completed by clicking the different questions and being lead to a viewcontroller which holds the options. lets call this the `OptionViewController`. Now I have 4 different forms with different options but all using `OptionViewController` to pull data from the database, I need to unwind the segue and pass data.

Since there might be 4 different view controllers it might be coming from, I need to make sure that the information is passed properly, i.e. identify if the destinationviewcontroller the unwindsegue is performing the first, second, third or fourth viewcontroller.

I thought I might do something like this

```
        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "optionSelected" {

        if segue.destinationViewController == FirstViewController {

             //pass data

        } else if segue.destinationViewController == SecondViewController {
             //pass data
        }

    }
}
```

But obviously I cannot perform `segue.destinationViewController == FirstViewController`

What should I actually be doing? Or should i just create one `OptionViewController` for every form, which would solve my problem, but I am not sure if overall the app performance will drop due to the increase of view controllers

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Try `if segue.destinationViewController is FirstViewController {`.  Or `if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? FirstViewController {`.

Comment: thanks for your quick suggestion. thats because my unwind segue method is by ctrl dragging my viewcontroller to exit. so unwind will exit the `OptionViewController` to the previous viewcontroller which might be any of the 4

Comment: vacawama `if segue.destinationViewController is FirstViewController {` works perfect for me. instead of `==` i should have used `is`. please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as answered thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if the destination view controller is of a specific class, use the Swift keyword `is`:

```
if segue.destinationViewController is FirstViewController {
```

Alternatively, you can assign the viewController to a variable using *optional binding* with an *optional cast*:

```
if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? FirstViewController {
    // dvc will have type FirstViewController so you can access specific
    // properties of FirstViewController using dvc
}
```